# How do I restrict the maximum height output of ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, 3d-printing

I'm doing an exploration of rational functions over the complex plane, and part of this is making 3D prints of graph outputs. Unfortunately, the asymptotes are proving too tall for the 3D printer to handle. I tried excluding the height by using `Exclusions -> {Abs[p/q] > 3}`, but this did not have the desired effect.

```
(*This is the input portion*)
MaxRadius = 3
p = v^3
q = (v + I) (v - I) (v + 1)
(*The rest is the integral code*)
v = r Cos[t] + I*r Sin[t]
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], Abs[p/q]}, {r, 0, MaxRadius}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
                 PlotStyle -> Thickness[.1], Exclusions -> {Abs[p/q] > 3}]
```

This plots all $|x|<3\in\mathbb{C}$ under $f(x)=\left|\dfrac{x^3}{x^3+x^2+x+1}\right|$. The goal is to exclude $x$ such that $f(x)>3$, thereby reducing the height of the print.

Comment: try the option `RegionFunction`?

Comment: What is `x`?  It appears nowhere in the code.

Comment: `RegionFunction -> (#3 <= 3 &)` or `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, t}, z <= 3]`

Comment: x is the standard variable that I use in my notes. in this case, it's equal to v, which is the variable I'm using for my functions. I'm using x as a dummy variable for other things in my code.

Comment: I've adapted my code using RegionFunction, but it only crops the real Asymptote; the asymptotes at |x|= _i_ are still way too tall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual procedure for enforcing constraints like yours is to use `Clip[]`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[With[{v = r Exp[I θ]},
                      {r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ],
                       Clip[Abs[v^3/((v + I) (v - I) (v + 1))], {0, 3}]}],
                 {r, 0, 3}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 105,
                 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.1]]
```

[image: rational function on a disk]

---

If one does not want the poles to be capped, one could use `Plot3D[]` over a disk, and restrict the `PlotRange`. `ClippingStyle -> None` ensures the poles aren't capped.

```
Plot3D[With[{v = x + I y}, Abs[v^3/((v + I) (v - I) (v + 1))]],
       {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 3], BoxRatios -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> None,
       Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 105, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-1/2, 3}},
       PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"]
```

[image: another way to clip]

Comment: `Clip` puts a "cap" on each of the spikes; whereas, `RegionFunction` truncates the spikes to show that they are hollow.

Comment: OTOH, the OP did not clarify on whether he wants the poles to be capped or not; let us wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: I never considered capped spikes, but they work well for my project, as the resulting print will be slightly more stable.